# How to retrieve data from the html table?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I will generate html table dynamically with some textbox and dropdownlist, user will enter their input in that. How to read these data in the controller?(MVC)

Comment: you might want to provide an example.

Comment: Is this all inside a form or just textboxes / lists ? In case it's not in a form, jQuery at the client side would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively quick and easy way to get data from a well-formatted HTML table using the Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB. Essentially, this allows you to specifiy a connection string which points at the page with your HTML table on it.

Here's an example connection string:

*Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=**http://www.your_web_address.com/yourHTMLTablePage.htm**;Extended Properties="HTML Import;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"*

You can the use the OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand objects to get to the data contained within the table. You can find these inside the namespace: **System.Data.OleDb**

I hope this helps?

/Richard.

Comment: <form method="post" action="">
    <table id="testTable" style="width: 100%;">
    <%for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
      { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="textBox1" name="textBox1" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%} %>
    </table>
  <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
This will generate 5 textboxes, i want to read the data entered in these text boxes when i click submit button. 

Thanks in advance